# How to use a old version of Unity in newer versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, downgrade

How can I use the older version of unity (4.03) found in ubuntu 11.10 on Ubuntu 13.04?
I understand that the new unity (7) has more improvements, but I just prefer the one in Ubuntu 11.10. Is it possible to install it? I have tried to add the old.ubuntu.releases archives and downgrading in synaptic to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible due dependencies on libraries not available on newer versions of Ubuntu. But if you have a specific problem in newer versions of Unity, please open a separated question.

**Newer version of Unity not only include improvements but also security and stability fixes**, older versions should be only used for testing/study/historic reasons, not on production/stable environment.