# How can I make Ubuntu 18.04 / 18.10 desktop use Unity (be like Ubuntu 14.04)?

Tags: 14.04, unity, 18.04, desktop-environments

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm not keen on the desktop environment. I want the desktop env. I used to have in Ubuntu 14.04. How can I get it?

I've attempted to use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/688932/73128), but when I try to install the Unity's 7.2.5 version using the command:

```
apt install unity=7.2.5
```

it gives me

```
E: Version '7.2.5' for 'unity' was not found
```

For sure I need to add a PPA for this, but which one!?

Comment: @karel nop it wasn't my answer i want the exact unity version used in ubuntu 14.04 which is `Unity 7.2.5` based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/688932/73128) answer. but when I try to install the `7.2.5` version using `apt install unity=7.2.5` it will give me the `E: Version '7.2.5' for 'unity' was not found`

Comment: In 18.04 you're going to get Unity 7.5.0, not exactly Unity 7.2.5 but pretty close and it's a lot more stable in 18.04 than 7.2.5.

Comment: Unity 7.2.5 needs the GTK+ 3.10 (from memory), where as the libraries & GTK+ version in 18.04 are 3.28 so the API/ABI's won't match and installing it won't help without a ton of extra libs, duplication of those libs etc.  I'd suggest using version 7.2.5 unless you're willing to do a ton of work  (*or are willing to use all 3.10 apps found in 14.04 anyway, so you'll end up with a 14.04 system with 18.04 kernel*)

Comment: @karel 7.2.5 it sucks... pretty but too god damn slow and buggy! The unity I used to have in 14.04 was perfect!

Comment: @guiverc the problems that I have with unity 7.2.5 just make me consider to crawl back to the Ubuntu 14.04 arms...  I am happy to do the ton of work if I know how to do it...

Comment: The work in my opinion isn't worth it, as you'll end up with a system that is only supported until 14.04 LTS reaches EOL next year anyway; so 14.04 would be an easier choice. I'd suggest trying 16.04 LTS out & its Unity version, and possibly using that version, and it has two years longer life than a 18.04 cludged to run 14.04 libs/apps would have of supported life.

Comment: Somehow or another Unity 7.5 in 18.04 got switched around to 7.2.5. 7.5 is the package maintainer's version in 18.04, not 7.2.5. And GNOME desktop environment in 18.04 is actually better than Unity was in 14.04 or 16.04, you just have to learn it and get used to it.

Comment: @karelit does not matter of learning it or getting used to it! it's just so bloody buggy or at least it's in my case.

Answer (score 12):

To install Unity you need to follow these steps:

- Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and use the following command:

  ```
  sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
  ```
- At the installation time, you’ll be asked whether you want to switch to LightDM.

  [image: Configuring lightdm]

  A Display manager is what you see on the login screen.

  - If you want Unity like login screen: select lightdm
  - If you want to keep the default login screen in Ubuntu 18.04: select gdm3

  Just select the one you want and press enter to move ahead with the installation procedure.

  [image: Choosing default display manager]
- Once the installation is complete, restart your system. At the login screen, click on the Ubuntu symbol in LightDM or gear symbol in GDM.

  [image: Login Screen]
- In here, you can see the option to use Unity desktop environment.

  [image: Choose Desktop environment]

Source: [It's FOSS](https://itsfoss.com/use-unity-ubuntu-17-10/)

Comment: I am already using the unity provided with this package.... it totally sucks! It has too many bugs to cope with. I want the unity I used in 14.04 back!

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/a/327431/816190

Comment: Actually it doesn't "suck", works better than the 14.04 version. Any "bugs" are 18.04 related and probably could be addressed. If you want 14.04 then go back to it..

Answer (score 1):

I think Tasksel is best and simplest way. Type:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

And then:

```
sudo tasksel
```

Uncheck GNOME desktop and check Ubuntu desktop. Then click OK. Reboot and you're done.

Comment: **Unchecking in `tasksel` is very dangerous. Do not do it!** See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1051440/66509) for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to install Ubuntu from **mini.iso - [Ubuntu Netboot images](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/)**.
When you're asked to choose any environment, don't check any and continue  installation.
Once the installation's completed, login into clear OS and install **Unity** by:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

That's it!
You'll get **absolutely clear Ubuntu 18.04/18.10 with only Unity/LightDM**