# 18.04 Dock Context Menus?

Tags: unity, 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, quodlibet

In the previous versions of Ubuntu, items on the dock had context menus that were per-application rather than dock related.

For instance, the quod libet context menu offered play, pause, stop etc.

Now I get a context menu that's related to the dock. This has happened for all applications.

How might I switch it back such that the context menu is per app rather than dock based?

Comment: Things have changed, Ubuntu now has GNOME instead of Unity and Unity Launcher and Ubuntu Dock are two different things. I'm not aware of the feature you're after for the new Ubuntu Dock. You may [switch back to Unity from GNOME](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040890/how-to-make-ubuntu-18-04-desktop-to-be-like-ubuntu-14-04-use-unity) if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Current context menu's on the dock also do contain app-specific options like before. For example, the right-click menu for firefox gives options to open a new window or to open a new private window. For Libreoffice, a new document can be created from the right-click menu. For Rhythmbox, you can Play/Pause, or skip to the next/previous song with the right-click menu.

The options for what to display in the right-click menu of a launcher are, as in previous versions of Ubuntu, defined by the application developer in the .desktop file that represents the launcher. That you now do not see them with Quod libet will be due to relevant items missing in the .desktop file of the application.