# Can I revert the 18.04 upgrade?

Tags: upgrade

I updated my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04, but I don't like the new update at all, is there anyway I can revert back to 16.04? Backup and restore maybe? I upgraded yesterday, a popup appeared told me there's a new version, and I clicked on upgrade now.

Comment: In my opinion, downgrading isn't an option.

Comment: What thing you don't like? May be that could be removed.

Comment: @Kulfy It's just very ugly, non-practical. I've only used it for a little while and it's an obvious downgrade from its predecessor.

Comment: Ugly, I guess you are referring to gnome, right? You can definitely go back to unity. This might help: https://askubuntu.com/a/1040897/816190. And what do you mean by non-practical?

Comment: @Kulfy Thanks, it's no longer ugly. But still very impractical, this is what I mean: https://i.imgur.com/MyXMjnH.png It's impossible to tell what I'm clicking on, what I'm hovering on, what setting is selected, what is on and what is off. You know how you're supposed to get a blue background over what's selected/hovered on? That doesn't exist. I'm inclined to believe that this is a bug because no way would anyone intentionally do this

Comment: Neve rmind, I changed the theme.