# How To Install Unity 8 On 18.04 and 18.10?

Tags: unity, 18.04, 18.10

**Unity 8, It is explained how to install on ubuntu 16.04,** But I want to know how to install it on ubuntu 18.04/18.10, like in this picture:

[The Ubuntu ScreenShot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vIpt.jpg)

Comment: It seems that currently Unity8 is not available (even in PPAs). So you may consider to install previous version as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1040897/66509).

Answer (score 1):

Unity 8 is an odd duck.  [Canonical dropped Unity in 2017](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity8Desktop), and Unity8 is not supported by https://unity8.io/, who state:

> Unity8 is not ready for production use on the desktop yet. However,
>   you can install a development preview on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 to
>   explore the current status. Visit our GitHub project to see what we
>   are workin on at the moment and where we could use your help.

The GitHub project is [at this location](https://github.com/ubports/unity8), and they have instructions for installation in https://github.com/ubports/unity8/blob/xenial/README.md

***However*** this is a development release of a product that canonical does not support.  This question might be marked as 'off-topic' as a result.