# Ubuntu 18.4 workspace switcher

Tags: 18.04, workspaces

On all my previous Ubuntu machines, I have had a small widget (2X2 grid) in the dock which enables me to switch to one of four workspaces. I have just purchased a new Ubuntu  machine and am trying to achieve the same effect. I do not want to use the method which involves going via Activities to the list on the right-hand side of the screen.

I recently upgraded an older Ubuntu machine to 18.4 and the workspace switcher continued to operate correctly there. The switcher is obviously compatible with Ubuntu 18.4 so how can I install it on my new machine?

Comment: This is done with a GNOME shell extension. Go to https://extensions.gnome.org and search for "workspace" and you'll find quite a selection.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 comes with GNOME instead of Unity, so the feature you're looking for is indeed not available by default. I believe the other system which you upgraded, still has and uses Unity, that's why you get the feature there. See this on how to install Unity on Ubuntu 18.04: https://askubuntu.com/q/1040890/480481