# Gnome crashed and return to login interface

Tags: gnome

My machine crashed around 07:03 and return to the login interface.

Here are the xsession-errors log

the short excerpt

```
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /home/gaowei/.config/SogouPY/punctures.ini failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_charvalid.bin 
May 14 07:03:43 alpha gnome-session[2538]: gnome-session-binary[2538]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha gnome-session-binary[2538]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
May 14 07:03:43 alpha gnome-session[2538]: gnome-session-binary[2538]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too q
May 14 07:03:43 alpha gnome-session[2538]: gnome-session-binary[2538]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code
```

The full excerpt:

```
May 14 07:03:45 alpha systemd[2474]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor...
May 14 07:03:43 alpha systemd[2474]: Started Sound Service.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha pulseaudio[8833]: E: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.594" (uid=1000 pid=8833 comm="/usr/bin/puls
May 14 07:03:43 alpha pulseaudio[8833]: E: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Failed to open mixer for jack detection
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_urlGuide.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_tip.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_urlGuide.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_tip.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_urlGuide.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_tip.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_urlGuide.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_tip.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_urlGuide.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_tip.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_urlGuide.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_tip.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_urlGuide.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_tip.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_urlGuide.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_tip.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_urlGuide.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_tip.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_urlGuide.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_tip.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_urlGuide.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_tip.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_urlGuide.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_tip.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_urlGuide.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_tip.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: check false, remove P
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /home/gaowei/.config/SogouPY/sgim_privilege.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: check false, remove A
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /home/gaowei/.config/SogouPY/sgim_phrases.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: check false, remove U
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /home/gaowei/.config/SogouPY/sgim_usr_v3_ext.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: check false, remove C
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file  failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: check false, remove C
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file  failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /home/gaowei/.config/SogouPY/punctures.ini failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: check false, remove P
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /home/gaowei/.config/SogouPY/punctures.ini failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2523]: open file /usr/share/fcitx-sogoupinyin/SogouInput/sgim_charvalid.bin failed.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha gnome-session[2538]: gnome-session-binary[2538]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
May 14 07:03:43 alpha gnome-session-binary[2538]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
May 14 07:03:43 alpha gnome-session[2538]: gnome-session-binary[2538]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
May 14 07:03:43 alpha gnome-session[2538]: gnome-session-binary[2538]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
May 14 07:03:43 alpha gnome-shell[8819]: Failed to create backend: Unable to open display ':0'
May 14 07:03:43 alpha pulseaudio[8833]: W: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Stale PID file, overwriting.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha gnome-session[2538]: gnome-session-binary[2538]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard.desktop' exited with code 1
May 14 07:03:43 alpha systemd[2474]: Starting Sound Service...
May 14 07:03:43 alpha systemd[2474]: Stopped Sound Service.
May 14 07:03:43 alpha systemd[2474]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
```

Is that the problem of my input method of sougou pinyin?

The problem started on Mar 22,  the detailed log

[Ubuntu Pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rtGjXggcBt/)

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic
```

Comment: Is the error reproducible or did it only happen once?

Comment: yes, repeat 2 to 4 times daily for months @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: If no one solves your problem, I would switch to the Unity Desktop and try that for awhile. It's all I've ever used and it's great IMO.

Comment: thank you, I pasted all the indentical failed log [Ubuntu Pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rtGjXggcBt/) @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: I didn't really do anything. Other than upvoting your question in the hopes someone using Gnome DE recognizes the problem. I did look at your paste. It would appear whales are highly coveted.

Comment: Yes, you help a lot . I appreciate it deeply. As a fresh, I once planed the last struggle and transmit to other distri, but our ubuntu commutiy  are so lovely to stay and grow along with.  @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: Thanks for the kind words Alice. Unity Desktop is Ubuntu. It is the "natural" desktop. Gnome Desktop, Kubuntu Desktop, Xubuntu Desktop, those are the "unnatural" ones. Unity Desktop is based on Gnome Desktop but more stringently tested for the Ubuntu Universe. Unity has fewer bells & whistles but greater stability: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040890/how-can-i-make-ubuntu-18-04-18-10-desktop-use-unity-be-like-ubuntu-14-04 You can install it and still switch to old broken Gnome desktop during login if you want.