# Ubuntu 18.04 Side Bar Icons Multiple App Instances Display On Click

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

In Ubuntu 18.04, when I click on a side bar (Ubuntu Dock) app icon representing multiple instances (for instance two terminals running) nothing happens.  In 16.04 I get separate windows displaying all app instances ready for clicking.

What am I missing?  Did I do something to offend thee?

Comment: The first click will bring up the most recently docked instance in the workspace and the second click (or double click) will bring up the chooser for all instances.  Check and see if that works for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong, but you're kinda comparing apples and oranges. Ubuntu 16.04 comes with Unity, whereas Ubuntu 18.04 comes with GNOME 3 instead of Unity. So it's not surprising that some things would be different.

You can activate a preview-on-click feature for the application icons in the Ubuntu Dock  (if it's not already activated) by running the following command in Terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'previews'
```

Then you should get something like this on mouse-click:
[image]

Alternatively, you can still install and use Unity on Ubuntu 18.04, refer to this: [How can I make Ubuntu 18.04 / 18.10 desktop use Unity (be like Ubuntu 14.04)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1040890/480481)

Comment: Thank you.  I wonder why this feature is hidden?

Comment: It should not be, rather it should be the default option. Probably it got misconfigured in your system for some reason.