# How can I make the icons in Ubuntu Dock slide when mouse hovered in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: unity, launcher, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I've been using Ubuntu 16.04 and there was a feature in the Unity Launcher: when mouse hovered to the top and bottom, the Launcher would move (slide) icons up and down respectively. It's not happening in the Ubuntu Dock after I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and I am facing a lot of trouble when multiple apps are opened, and trying to switch between them.

**Ubuntu 16.04 Launcher feature explanation:**
If you open more applications than can be shown in the Launcher, the Launcher will “fold” the application icons at the bottom of the Launcher. By Simply moving the mouse to the bottom of the Launcher,the Launcher icons “slide” and the folded application icons unfold for easy access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is not available *yet* in Ubuntu Dock (note that Ubuntu Dock in GNOME 3 environment and the Launcher in Unity are two separate things).

When you have too many applications open so that all of them don't appear in the dock, you can simply use you *mouse's scroll wheel* (or touchpad's scrolling feature) to *scroll* the icons up or down in order to reveal the hidden ones in the top or bottom.

*Note:* It is still [possible to use Unity](https://askubuntu.com/a/1040897/480481) on Ubuntu 20.04 instead of the default GNOME 3.