# How to change preview windows on Ubuntu dock

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, launcher, ubuntu-dock

I have updated my Ubuntu to 18.04 and facing an UX issue. The new UX has a preview option for grouped windows. For example, when I click Firefox, with multiple open windows, I am getting a preview and I have to select one from this. Given the size of the preview, it is hardly useful, especially when I am coding using the terminal.

[image]

I believe the preview on earlier Ubuntu versions is that both windows are shown open bigger side-by-side if I recall properly. Either this or there was no preview and the most recently opened window will open automatically on clicking the Firefox icon and then I can `Alt`+`~` to the other Firefox window. Can someone suggest how to achieve the previous UX as in earlier Ubuntu versions?

Comment: If this is absolutely important to you, then you can still use Unity with Ubuntu 18.04 like older releases: [How can I make Ubuntu 18.04 / 18.10 desktop use Unity (be like Ubuntu 14.04)?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1040890/480481)

Comment: Thanks much! I still do not understand why Ubuntu chose the new UX, which on many fronts really counter productive!